# Obtaining Default Color for OS in C

Tags: c, assembly, colors, operating-system

Ok, so a little background to what I'm doing. I'm developing an OS with a small file system. It's written in part assembler and part C. I'm trying to implement hot keys to make the system cycle through colors, swap foreground and background colors, clear the screen completely, etc. Here's the function I'm currently working with

```
PRIVATE void my_toy_shell(u16_t key) {
u32_t color = 0;
char fg_color, bg_color, newcolor;

// Colors
newcolor = 0x2a;
fg_color = 0x0E;
bg_color = 0x10;

switch(key) {
    case C('D'):        /* ctrl-d set default color */
        newcolor = 0x1E;
        color = newcolor;
        __clr_screen(color,_NO_FILL);
        break;

    case C('S'):        /* ctrl-s swap bg and fg color */
        bg_color = color & 0xF0;
        fg_color = color & 0x0F;
        newcolor = fg_color | bg_color;
        color = newcolor;
        __clr_screen(color,_NO_FILL);
        break;

    case C('F'):        /* ctrl-f  cycle fg color */
        if(fg_color == 0x0F)
            fg_color = 0x00;
        else
            fg_color<<;
        color = bg_color | fg_color;
        __clr_screen(color, _NO_FILL);
        break;

    case C('G'):        /* ctrl-g cycle bg color */
        /*if(bg_color == 0x70)*/
        break;

    case C('Q'):        /* ctrl-q  reset */
        /*Clears screen*/
        __clr_screen(_IOTA_TTY_COLOR,_FILL_BLANK);
        _display_welcome();
        break;
    }
}
```

For now just to verify that the functions are working, I've hardcoded "newcolor", "fg_color", and "bg_color".
CTRL-D does it's correct function, as well as CTRL-Q.
CTRL-S is supposed to swap the foreground and background colors.
This is where I become confused. In order to swap the current colors on screen, I was told to the color with 0x0F or 0xF0 depending on which value I wanted to obtain for either fg or bg. However I'm not sure how to get the current color that's being displayed on screen. The default is yellow on blue (0x1E). I also found that when I tried the other colors, anything above a hex value of 8 will give me the colors for 0-7 but it causes the screen to blink. Using the bitwise "&" and "|" should allow me to get the corresponding values I need to swap. However my problem is obtaining the current color on screen. I'm not sure if this is something I need to try to find within my file elsewhere, or if there is something built into C that I could use to get those values

EDIT: I figured it out. Turns out I had an attribute in another file that was imported into this file called `_color_attr` which contained the current color.

Comment: `__clr_screen` is a function that takes 2 parameters, a color, and a word attribute it appears. When using "_FILL_BLANK" it will clear everything on the screen, when using "_NO_FILL" it will leave everything else on the screen unmodified. This is a user defined function in another file that gets imported into this file. I'm basically using this function to keep everything on the screen when needed, and clearing the screen when required, as when pressing CTRL-Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bg_color = color & 0xF0;
fg_color = color & 0x0F;
newcolor = fg_color | bg_color;
color = newcolor;
```

The previous code does not swap colors! Use

```
bg_color = (color & 0xF0) / 16;
fg_color = (color & 0x0F) * 16;
newcolor = fg_color | bg_color;
color = newcolor;
```

> However my problem is obtaining the current color on screen

You could directly read the attribute byte of the first character displayed on screen. It's linear address is 0xB8001.
There's also the nice video BIOS function 8 that can help you retrieve the current color.

> I also found that when I tried the other colors, anything above a hex value of 8 will give me the colors for 0-7 but it causes the screen to blink.

To disable blinking use video BIOS function 16 with AL=3 and BL=0

Comment: This helped a lot! After thinking about it a lot, I needed to shift the colors left and right correspondingly

`bg_color = bg_color >> 4;
fg_color = fg_color << 4;
newcolor = bg_color | fg_color;
color - newcolor;`

There was also an attribute in a another file after looking called `_color_attr` which contained the current color so after doing the bitwise and, I was able to get what I needed.